# How to print odd/even next to the multiples of a table asked by user in a C program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, range, i;
    printf("Enter an integer to find multiplication table: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter range of multiplication table:");
    scanf("%d",&range);
    for(i=1;i<=range;++i)
{
    printf("%d * %d = %d\n", n, i, n*i);
}
return 0;
```

}

I need to display odd next to multiples that are odd and even next to even multiples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `printf()` statement to:

```
printf ( "%d * %d = %d : %s\n", n, i, n*i, (n*i % 2 == 0) ? "EVEN" : "ODD" );
```

The modulus operator gives the remainder of n divided by 2.

Comment: (n*i) is the one that needs to be checked, I was thinking of replacing the "i" in the code with "(n*i)" , will test it when I go home and see if it works.

Comment: I have editted the code and replaced 'i' to 'n*i'.
I hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

```
if ((n*i)%2 == 0)
  printf("EVEN : %d * %d = %d\n", n, i, n*i);
else
  printf("ODD : %d * %d = %d\n", n, i, n*i);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check if a number is **even** or **odd** is by using **bitwise operators**.

`if (i & 1) { // It's odd }`

`else { //it is even }`